# React Native Previous scene is below the current scene

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigator

I'm getting a weird bug that I've never experienced before in React Native. I'm using the latest version of react native and the built in navigator. When I transition from the ListView to the next scene as shown on the video below, the ListView scene seems to now be below the current scene. I have slow animations turned on in order to amplify the effect. I can't figure out what's going on. I'm just using a basic push pop - no LayoutAnimations or anything.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkfVw9aCC3Y

Comment: Any way you can show your navigation code?

Comment: It's just a regular push and pop. I figured out what it is though. When I go to the route, I'm making an API call on componentWillMount which updates that specific ListView item (with additional data from the API call). If I remove this API call, this never happens. In fact, I check to see if the ListView item has additional data before making the api call. If it does, this bug doesn't happen either...I'm very confused.

Comment: Ok I fixed it by initiating the additional fields that the API call give you with default values. Now it worked as expected. I'm still confused as to why that API call would give this result though...